# uniform distribution homogeneity test

Tags: probability

I want to test for homogeneity. I know there is a chi-quadrat-test, but are there any more homogeneity tests for uniform distributions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose you're talking about _discrete_ uniform distributions. If you're doing the equivalent of checking a die (6 categories) or a US roulette wheel (38) for 'fairness', then a chi-squared test of goodness-of-fit to the relevant discrete uniform distribution may be the best solution.

Comment: Can you more clearly explain what you mean by "homogeneity" in this instance? Can you confirm that by "chi quadrat test" you mean chi-squared test? Are you trying to as whether there are other goodness of fit tests of uniformity than the chi-squared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two quick examples of the `chisq.test` procedure in R:

A fair roulette wheel vinidicated by tabulating 5000 spins: P-value > 0.05.

```
set.seed(2019)
spin = sample(1:38, 5000, rep=T)
TABr = tabulate(spin)
chisq.test(TABr)$p.val
[1] 0.3426727
```

Crooked die (favoring `6`'s over `1`'s) detected,
based on 600 rolls: P-value near 0.

```
prob = c(2,3,3,3,3,4)/18
roll = sample(1:6, 600, rep=T, p=prob)
TABd = tabulate(roll)
chisq.test(TABd)$p.val
[1] 0.0001834828
```